# Using Android XMLPullParser to Navigate/Parse XML

Tags: android, xml, listview, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am new to coding and trying to understand how Android's XMLPullParser navigates a given XML.  Below is an example of the XML where I am only interested in pulling the attribute information in Child 1.

How do you tell the Android XMLPullParser to only care about information within a specific tag (Child 1) while ignoring other tags that contain similar data?

Example:

```
<root>
<child 1>
      <child 1.1>
                 <attribute 1></attribute 1>
                 <attribute 2></attribute 2>
      </child 1.1>


      <child 1.2>
                 <attribute 1></attribute 1>
                 <attribute 2></attribute 2>
      </child 1.2>

</child 1>

<child 2>
      <child 2.1>
                 <attribute 1></attribute 1>
                 <attribute 2></attribute 2>
      </child 2.1>

      <child 2.2>
                 <attribute 1></attribute 1>
                 <attribute 2></attribute 2>
      </child 2.2>
</child 2>
</root>
```

Thanks!

**Tutorials Attempted:**

- http:// developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
- http:// theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xmlpullparser-tutorial/

Comment: pull parsing is known to be difficult to code, espectially the sturcture of xml is complex... are you open to other apis?

Comment: Yes open to any others. My end goal is to present the parsed data in a listview contained in a fragment.

Comment: Can you clarify what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: Yes, I just added an image in the OP with an example of the desired output.  Also, tossed in the link to the actual live XML.

Comment: would you be ok with code that extracts the field from xml and display in a table and take it to fit your purposes?

Comment: Yup. Open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer by focusing on exactly how the PullParser was looping through the XML.  Generally, I found that the style used in the android developer documentation was difficult to adjust so that it would parse one level deeper than the example.

My solution came from using a "done" flag to cut the parsing short of the end of the document.  In my case, I set the done flag to switch to "TRUE" once the Parser detected the Child 2 tag from the above example.  That way all the duplicate attributes in Child 2 were totally ignored and I only received the attributes from Child 1.

The below is guide is what gave me the idea for using the "done" flag.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Hope it helps anyone who has a similar problem.